# How should declare SWIG interface if some types can be wrapped with either shared_ptr or just value type?

Tags: c#, c++, swig, smart-pointers

In SWIG, I tried to use shared_ptr as below.

```
class Member {
  
};

class Parent {
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<Member> member_;
};

class OtherParent {
  private:
    Member member_;
}

%shared_ptr(Member)
```

However, `%shared_ptr` directive seems it turns `std::shared_ptr<Member>` into Member class in target language. Then if I want `Member` class to be declared as value type how should I deal with it?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to `%template(MemberPtr) std::shared_ptr<Member>;`  then `%shared_ptr(MemberPtr)`.
However I am not sure it is right